# Typescript erroring on property defined in subclass in javascript file

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, jsdoc

I'm using Typescript to check my Javascript files. When I extend from a class, Typescript no longer knows the types of the properties in the parent class. I'm curious if I'm missing something obvious, or if Typescript simply doesn't support checking this:

```js
class Foo {

/**
 * @param {number} a
 */
  constructor(a) {

    this.a = a;

  }
}

class Bar extends Foo {

  constructor() {
    super(5);
  }

  move() {
     const foo = this.a + 5;
     this.a = foo;

  }

}
```

Error:

```
    'foo' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer.
    'a' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer.
```

I would have expected Typescript to understand that `this.a` has the type `number`, because it *does* understand this when the property is defined in the current class (instead of a parent class)

Comment: It works when you explicitly declare the type of `a`: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ1pmgLmgOwFcBbAIwFMAnAbnWmHjwgBcKDgn4KAKLXQ0ygEoUtDEwAWASwgA6LAF5MNDAF9Ua0JBgAhMBWhkAHkzJ4AJjARI0GeoxZsO3YTYzQIBAA6UuAVkHK0GoYRPAAbmRcLqK2DMzQAGaI0IoS0nLQANTQvoFuabIKiYiBahpx8CBkMiDwAOZceGQA7tC6znIBQA

Comment: Test things out in the playground first please. Are you asking about code you're not showing us? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8CwAoDB6AVDj0O0AAgA5gBOYAtigHYCu1ARgKYUC+0YBOWB0YPDoQALhQbBR8CgAowAShQYB0aKIAWASwgA6MNAC83ANwr0ajhiuZ0oSDABClaKwAeo1nQAmMBEjRbNSERcUlpOSVAtTUIBlJ2WQBWBTMLaBsBangAN1ZZKNVg4TFoADNEI3VtPQMAamgktJi1TR19Kor4NIFM9A4gA "and is referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer." has nothing to do with the code you posted

Comment: @Unmitigated I'm typechecking a Javascript file, so that won't work!

Comment: @AndyRay take a look at this playground link: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?filetype=js#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8CwAoDB6AVDj0O0AAgA5gBOYAtigHYCu1ARgKYUC+0YBOWB0YPDoQALhQbBR8CgAowAShQYB0aKIAWASwgA6MNAC83ANwr0ajhiuZ0oSDABClaKwAeo1nQAmMBEjRbNSERcUlpOSVAtTUIBlJ2WQBWBTMLaBsBangAN1ZZKNVg4TFoADNEI3VtPQMAamgktJi1TR19Kor4NIFM9A4gA . It has those exact errors

Comment: [Equivalent TS](https://tsplay.dev/mbEL8N) — @Evert [using `super` to set the property on the owner](https://tsplay.dev/mAJOkW) works as expected (and compiles). Would you like to see that as an answer or am I still missing something?

Comment: @jsejcksn interesting! any idea why `super` is needed? `this` should also just access the parent's properties. It works as expected in Javascript so I rather continue to use `this` to give further downstream subclasses a chance to further extend this.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75718179/typescript-erroring-on-property-defined-in-subclass-in-javascript-file#comment133574790_75718179) @Evert "_why `super` is needed_": It's not **needed** — you could [cast](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html#casts) instead to avoid circular inference (example: https://tsplay.dev/mpjabw) — but setting it that way preserves ownership (location) of the value: on the [prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super) (foo)...

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75718179/typescript-erroring-on-property-defined-in-subclass-in-javascript-file#comment133574901_75718179) It's a subtle behavioral difference: property accesses walk the prototype chain for resolution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `move` method on `Bar`, there's a circular type inference: you set `Bar.a` to the value `foo`, which is computed using `Bar.a` without an explicit annotation — thus the error:

> ... implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer.(7022)

Here are three solutions:

1. Prevent the unnecessary inference — don't use an intermediate variable:

   [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&filetype=js#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ1oHoBU3oAEAHMAJzAFsUA7AV3ICMBTEgX2jGm03WmHiogAXEjWCD4JABRgAlCh4ZBACwCWEAHQcAvOwDcPFqkOpQkGACFS0RgA9BjKgBMYCJGgx8Bw0eKlz3GNAQNITMkgCsMvoYxhjk8ABujJL+CtDKaprQOhkaHADU0OHR0IbGnkLQ9FY6VIwA7tCWfvoV8CCM6iDwAOaS1SSaUViYWgB8RagD6vFJKa38EO2d3X3Tsroj49AAjAAMU6QziclRJovLXb39RxtbEzvhqEA)

   ```ts
   move() {
     this.a = this.a + 5;
   }
   ```
2. Explicitly [annotate (cast)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html#casts) the type of `foo`:

   [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&filetype=js#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ1oHoBU3oAEAHMAJzAFsUA7AV3ICMBTEgX2jGm03WmHiogAXEjWCD4JABRgAlCh4ZBACwCWEAHQcAvOwDcPFqkOpQkGACFS0RgA9BjKgBMYCJGgx8Bw0eKlz3GNAQNITMkgCsMvoYxhjk8ABujJL+Crz8QtAAZojQOjh4+IIAnqHUdEysnJiSymqa0ADU0JHRgXUa2tmIbYbGnpn0VjpUjADu0JZ++gPwIIzqIPAA5pJDJJpRWJhaAHwtqOvq8UkpMxlzC0urR7K623vQAIwADIekx4nJUSYX84srNYfO4PfZPcKoIA)

   ```ts
   move() {
     const foo = /** @type {number} */(this.a + 5);
     this.a = foo;
   }
   ```
3. Get the value from `this` (`Bar`), but set the value to [`super`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super) (`Foo`) — and maintain discrete inference sites:

   [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&filetype=js#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ1oHoBU3oAEAHMAJzAFsUA7AV3ICMBTEgX2jGm03WmHiogAXEjWCD4JABRgAlCh4ZBACwCWEAHQcAvOwDcPFqkOpQkGACFS0RgA9BjKgBMYCJGgx8Bw0eKlz3GNAQNITMkgCsMvoYxhjk8ABujJL+Crz8QtAAZojQOspqmtAA1NDh0YHBoSRFOjnwFYbGnpn0VjpUjADu0JZ++i3wIIzqIPAA5pJtNbK6WJhaAHxlqNPq8UkpAxlDI2OTa7PzS9AAjAAMq6TriclRJjvDoxNT10eYC8un4ahAA)

   ```ts
   move() {
     const foo = this.a + 5;
     super.a = foo;
   }
   ```

   Accesses of the property `a` on instances of `Bar` will still resolve from the prototype property.

Answer (score -1):

> I would have expected TypeScript to understand that this.a has the type number

The thing you're expecting is called "Type Inference". TypeScript is pretty smart to infer the type, but it can't infer type when it is not so obvious from the source code.

For example, TS can deterministically infer that `a` is `number` here.

```js
let a = 5;
```

But, it cannot deterministically infer that `a` is `number` here.

```js
function foo(x) {
    return x;
}

let a = foo(5);
```

The doc comment,

```js
/**
 * @param {number}
 */
```

is not standard TypeScript, so that will not help you in any way.

Comment: [JSDoc annotations **are** standard TS](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html), and are used just like type annotations for inference: Info from [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/75718647/1) in the playground to demonstrate: https://tsplay.dev/wXOZoW

Comment: @jsejcksn Sorry, my bad! By saying "not standard TS", I meant that comments are just comments, meaning they are ignore by TS compiler, and you can't enforce a type rule using comments.